# how to install zend framework 2 in netbeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-7.3

I've installed the plugin php zend framework 2 in netbeans 7.3

But I can not create a zendFrameWork2 project !

How do I install zend framework 2 in netbeans 7.3 ?

Thanks

Comment: I added zend skeleton application.zip to my netbeans->tools but This error occurs when creating a new zend framework2 project : Composer must be selected.

Answer (score 6):

You need download the Zend Skeleton Application in

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app

like this zendframework-ZendSkeletonApplication-zf-release-2.1.0-20-g619a8d7.zip

next

you need go to http://getcomposer.org/download/

and download windows installer

this installer need find your php.exe file

generaly in C:\xamp\php\php.exe

and install this

now find your composer.phar file

ok this is all

Comment: Its not, now i have composer installed and netbeans throw the same warning: "Composer must be selected".